# Byte order (endian) of int in NSLog?

Tags: c, format, endianness, specifier

NSLog function accepts printf format specifiers.
My question is about %x specifier.
Does this print hex codes as sequence on memory? Or does it have it's own printing sequence style?

```
unsigned int a = 0x000000FF;
NSLog(@"%x", a);
```

Results of above code on little or big endian processors are equal or different?
And how about NSString's -initWithFormat method? Does it follows this rule equally?

Comment: Why would you expect `NSLog` to be any different in `printf` in this regard?  Or are you asking about `printf` too?

Comment: Yes, you're right. They're equal. I'm asking about printf too. I saw the linked printf document from NSLog's description, but I couldn't find any direct mention about byte order. And I don't know underlying system of C well. So I couldn't sure about it. That's the reason of why I asked this here. For conviction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%x always prints the most significant digits first. Doesn't matter what kind of processor it is running on.

Comment: @Carl can you tell me more specifically? Did you mean byte order can be different by machine?

Comment: @Eonil, yeah for sure.  For example, PowerPC macs are big-endian, and Intel macs are little-endian.